# How do I compile Bash 4 with Clang 14 on an M1 Mac with macOS 13?

Tags: bash, compilation, clang

I cloned the latest Bash's source code (`ec8113b9 * Bash-5.2 patch 15: fix too-aggressive optimizing forks out of subshell commands`) and compiled it like this

```bash
cd /tmp
git clone https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/bash.git
cd bash

./configure && make
```

However when I try to compile Bash 4 with

```bash
git checkout -- .  # clear files generated by the first compilation
git checkout 64447609 # the commit before bash-5.0, the last Bash 4 commit
./configure && make
```

I get this error:

```
/usr/homes/chet/src/bash/src/parse.y:5741:21: error: implicit declaration of function 'count_all_jobs' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
              temp = itos (count_all_jobs ());
                           ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [y.tab.o] Error 1
```

I tried

```bash
CFLAGS="-std=c89" ./configure && make
```

but got the same error.

I have this compiler:

```bash
$ clang --version
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: As `configure`d, the version of the code you are trying to compile is flawed.  This may simply indicate that your target machine is not supported by the build system.  Chances are good that the issue could be fixed, but the information presented in the question is nowhere near enough to inform a specific answer about that.

Comment: @JohnBollinger why does it give me an error about c99 if I requested c89?