# How do I compile Bash as a shared library?

Tags: gcc, compilation, shared-libraries

I want to use Bash's [parser](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/ec8113b9861375e4e17b3307372569d429dec814/command.h#L197) from Python or JavaScript. Bash wasn't written with this kind of usage in mind, so I understand that I will have to change the code to do things like defer looking up variables like what [they did](https://github.com/verhovsky/bash2py/compare/4a7afe168e3d7a14070981e5e8d807e8e6668a25...verhovsky:bash2py:bash2py-3) for [Bash2Py](https://www.swag.uwaterloo.ca/bash2py/index.html),  but to start with I want to get a working workflow where I can call Bash functions from Python with [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) or from JavaScript through Node-API or Web Assembly.

Comment: I figured it out but because I used ChatGPT I'm not allowed to post an answer here.

Comment: Why don't you write up the answer in your own words, then?

Comment: @AlexReinking I did that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75908689/how-do-i-compile-bash-4-with-clang-14-on-an-m1-mac-with-macos-13/75909834#75909834) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75966933/how-do-i-send-an-empty-json-dictionary-with-guzzle/75966934#75966934) and those answers got deleted and I got warned to not do it again. I guess it's okay to use it but against the rules to speak its name in the answer, and I would feel dishonest if I omitted that detail.